# What code removes the admin bar for all users in WordPress 3.3?

Tags: admin-bar

How can I remove the admin bar in both the front and backend for all users in WordPress 3.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* Front end */
show_admin_bar( false );

/* back end */
function disableAdminBar(){
    remove_action( 'admin_footer', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 1000 );  
    function remove_admin_bar_style_backend() {  
        echo '<style>body.admin-bar #wpcontent, body.admin-bar #adminmenu { padding-top: 0px !important; }</style>';
    }  
    add_filter('admin_head','remove_admin_bar_style_backend');  
}
add_action('init', 'disableAdminBar');
```

Modified version of http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-disable-the-admin-bar-in-wordpress-3-3/

Answer (score 2):

This in functions.php: `add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );`

Edit: For the front-end.